# Improve the speed of $lookup on a large dataset collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, php-mongodb

I have a collection on products on which i would like to implement `search` using `title` and `author` and on the basis of that I would like to filter on my results. So since my data set is quite big around 1 million so I created an Index for `title` and `author` and it works great, results are fetched under 20ms.

But I want to get some additional data using a `$lookup` from another collection called `vendor_products` , no since `vendor_products` has also around 1 million entries the `$lookup` takes up a lot of time , and my query ends ups taking 1000ms .

So is there any way to optimize it.

PRODUCTS collection ('has around a million entries')
I have created the index for author and title

```
{
'_id'=>'ObjectId('...')',
'title'=>'Harry Potter',
'author'=>'J.K Rowling',
'vendor_product_id'=>'ObjectId('...')'
'other_data'...
}
```

VENDOR PRODUCTS

```
{
  '_id'=>'ObjectId('...')',
  'product_id'=>'ObjectId('...')',
  'data'=>['data i need to fetch']
}

[
       '$match'=>['$text'=> ['$search'=> $search_query ] ] 
],
  [
       '$lookup' => [
       'from' => 'vendor_products',
       'localField' => '_id',
       'foreignField' => 'product_id',
       'as' => 'vendor_products'
  ]
],
```

Comment: Do you have an index on `product_id` field?

Comment: yes i have created one using this command `db.vendor_products.createIndex({'product_id':1})`

Comment: Now run the query and check the response time

Comment: thank you , it's coming around 120 ms